# FindBugs: Unit test package dependency rules?

Tags: java, junit, circular-dependency, findbugs

I want to enforce certain dependency rules in our code base: e.g. package A should not depend on package B, no circular dependencies etc. And I think the only way that is able to enforce them are (failing) tests, not reports.

So I looked around and found [JDepend](http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html), [Classycle](http://classycle.sourceforge.net) and JBoss [TattleTale](http://tattletale.jboss.org) - all appear to be discontinued and lacking Java 8 support. That's when I discovered FindBugs.

So I want to use FindBugs to analyze our package structure and use JUnit to validate certain rules about their relations. But since the FindBugs source code is *huge*, I'm wondering: **How do I achieve this?**

Regards,
Stephan

Answer (score 2):

You can use Degraph for this task: http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2014/07/27/test-your-dependencies-with-degraph/

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can use [ArchUnit](https://www.archunit.org/) to declare allowed/disallowed dependencies between packages in a form of unit test (JUnit or other test framework), there are [some examples in their user guide](https://www.archunit.org/userguide/html/000_Index.html#_package_dependency_checks), a sample looks like this:

```java
noClasses().that().resideInAPackage("..utils..")
    .should().dependOnClassesThat().resideInAPackage("..domain..")
```